# Place text in top line, right justified for each paragraph

Tags: cv

I am working on a CV and I would like to put the year of activity xyz in the top right corner of each paragraph. Normally, I would use \hfill, but for my longer entries, the year overflows the next line when I would prefer that the text description of each activity wrap around instead.

```
    \section{\textnormal{\textbf{RANDO}}}
    \emph{HONOR HONOR HONOR} used for study in Harvard University's Business            
    Economics Program \hfill 2016-present \\ [0.1cm]
    \emph{HONOR HONOR HONOR 2} for Yale University's doctorate in finance           
    (declined) \hfill 2016
```

What I want is to guarantee that each date is on the top line of its paragraph on the right hand side of the page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post an example of the code you have so far?

Comment: Are you sure you want the year on the right? This is very unusual. Did you take a look at the different cv packages that exist in distributions, TeX Live as well as MiKTeX. One of the most popular is `moderncv`.

Comment: To be frank, I don't think this is very unusual at all for an academic CV (at least in finance). Here is the CV of the former editor of the Journal of Finance, for instance: http://bus.miami.edu/_assets/files/faculty-cv/finance/harvey_CV_October_2010.pdf, and here is the CV of Nobel Laureate Bob Shiller http://capitalism.columbia.edu/files/ccs/person/cv/2015/vita10_shiller_cc.pdf. I looked at the other CV formats, and found nothing that met my needs.

Comment: But in these exaples, no year is at the rightmost top corner of each paragraph! Or did I misunderstand what you want?

Comment: Technically, both lines in the MWE are in the same paragraph.  I take it you want the text to wrap around the date, or do you want the date to be outside the right margin?

Comment: Bernard, you asked if the year being on the right was common. The CV's I provided give examples in which the year is on the right hand side. My request is indeed more specific than that present in the example CV's I gave.

Comment: John Kormylo, you are right. I want the text to wrap around the date, which would always be on the first line.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a special `\documentclass`, you may need to enlarge `\marginparwidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{\textnormal{\textbf{RANDO}}}\leavevmode
    \marginpar{\hfill 2016-present}%
    \emph{HONOR HONOR HONOR} used for study in Harvard University's Business            
    Economics Program\\[0.1cm]
    \marginpar{\hfill 2016}%
    \emph{HONOR HONOR HONOR 2} for Yale University's doctorate in finance           
    (declined)
\end{document}
```

You can also use tabularx:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\section{\textnormal{\textbf{RANDO}}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}Xp{1in}@{}}
    \emph{HONOR HONOR HONOR} used for study in Harvard University's Business            
    Economics Program & 2016-present \\[0.1cm]
    \emph{HONOR HONOR HONOR 2} for Yale University's doctorate in finance           
    (declined) & 2016
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

You can flow the text around the date using `\hangindent`.  For convenience, I created the length `\datewidth` and the macro `\myformat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newlength{\datewidth}
\setlength{\datewidth}{1in}

\newcommand{\myformat}[1]% #1 = date field
{\par\hangindent=-\datewidth
 \hangafter=-1
 \noindent\rlap{\hspace{\dimexpr \textwidth-\datewidth}\makebox[\datewidth][r]{#1}}%
}
\begin{document}
\section{\textnormal{\textbf{RANDO}}}
    \myformat{2016-present}%
    \emph{HONOR HONOR HONOR} used for study in Harvard University's Business            
    Economics Program \blindtext
    \vspace{0.1cm}\myformat{2016}%
    \emph{HONOR HONOR HONOR 2} for Yale University's doctorate in finance           
    (declined)
\end{document}
```

This variant uses a variable width date field.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newsavebox{\datebox}% \hangindent global

\newcommand{\myformat}[1]% #1 = date field
{\savebox{\datebox}{\hspace{1em}\textbf{#1}}%
  \par\hangindent=-\wd\datebox
  \hangafter=-1
  \noindent\rlap{\hspace{\dimexpr \linewidth-\wd\datebox}\usebox{\datebox}}%
}
\begin{document}
\section{\textnormal{\textbf{RANDO}}}
    \myformat{2016-present}%
    \emph{HONOR HONOR HONOR} used for study in Harvard University's Business            
    Economics Program \blindtext
    \vspace{0.1cm}\myformat{2016}%
    \emph{HONOR HONOR HONOR 2} for Yale University's doctorate in finance           
    (declined)
\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer is sufficient for my needs but does not actually answer the question. I want it to be possible for the text describing each activity to wrap underneath the year (this is what makes the question different from previous CV solutions I found on StackOverflow), but neither of your solutions allow for that.

Comment: I suspected as much, but this was a lot easier.

Comment: Your addendum has two problems in my ShareLaTeX setup. First, it seems to start each activity with "-=-1" and second, the text of the activity overlaps the date.  Screenshot attached with \blindtext removed for readability: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B02KoGnAn1VOWVR4WWduSXQ5Snc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you get any error mesages?  If \hangindent or \hangafter are undefined, or \datewidth is already defined, that might explain the behavior described.